# How to implement a restriction to create AT MOST one null value in a column

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to implement a sort of tree in the table employee, where each employee except for one has a supervisor, who is another employee in the same table. The one with a NULL value in their supervisor slot would be the "manager" or something. Is there a way to implement it? I know in other languages this would be trivial with a partial index, but Mysql doesn't support those, so I'm at a loss.

Here's the table declaration I made without this restriction, and for the record, employee is meant to be one of four specializations of the person table, with further specialization into either associates or partners:

```
create table employee
(
    ID              numeric(7,0),
    supervisor_ID   numeric(7,0),
    postition       enum('associate','partner') NOT NULL,
    primary key (ID),
    foreign key (ID) references person(ID),
    foreign key (supervisor_ID) references employee(ID)
);
```

Comment: Maybe a trigger that counts the number of rows with supervisor_ID IS NULL, and signals an error if there's more than one.

Comment: Could it be a possibiliry to not use null but for example a negative number, or 0 ?

Comment: @LaurentS. Then it would fail the foreign key constraint.

Comment: And that doesn't solve the problem of restricting it to just one employee.

Comment: BTW, wouldn't the one with no supervisor be the CEO?

Comment: Not all business rules can be encoded in SQL schema. It seems like this is better handled in the applications.

Comment: @Barmar It could be the CEO, I didn't bother asking.

Comment: Who else doesn't have a supervisor? If it's a department manager, you need to allow more than 1, since there's a different one for each department.

Comment: @Barmar This database is meant to be simpler than that. It's supposed to cover like, a realty group or something? Point is there are no "departments" to worry about. This DB isn't covering the whole business, just the people involved in the viewing and leasing of the houses. Part of the design specs was that the employees should be part of a rooted tree with one employee at the root without a supervisor, and all other employees are somewhere in that tree. I also just realized that the rooted-ness means I need to also make sure there are no cycles. Gonna have to figure that out too.

Comment: I just mean whoever is the highest person in the entire organization, whatever that is.

Comment: All these business rules need to be implemented in the application, you can't encode them in the DB itself, at least with MySQL.

Comment: ...although this doesn't look like MySQL. Anyway, aren't you simply saying that there can only be one manager?

Comment: This sounds like something better suited to a nested set model - whereby the min left value and max right value must belong to the same person.